# Proper way to ignore source files during Perforce integration

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

In my primary branch there is a change list with 10 files that I'm trying to integrate into a development branch. All of the outstanding files in the change list should be ignored, and not branched into the target.

What are the steps to do the integration so that Perforce does not create the files in the target branch, and ignores the change list files for all future integrations?

I originally did an integration with `-Dt`, and then reverted the 10 files I did not want to be created in the target branch. After this, Perforce continues to try and re-integrate these files to the target.

Maybe this is part of the issue or irrelevant, but the source files are not textual edits, but updates to the filetype fields

Answer (score 4):

Integrate the file, then do 'accept yours' when you are resolving. That tells the server that you want to explicitly ignore the change from the other branch, and the server won't subsequently include that change in future integrations.

Comment: If I merge with -Dt there are no conflicts to resolve. The files do not exist on the target side. What I select "re-resolve previously merged" the file list is empty.

Comment: You may need a fairly new version of the server to do this. The ability to resolve deletes like this was added in 2011.

Comment: This doesn't answer this part of the question: "What are the steps to do the integration so that Perforce does not create the files in the target branch".

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
p4 integrate -Rb -Rd -b <branch>
```

Then in P4V, Resolve --> Accept Target.

See [here](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_integrate.html) for information on the -Rb and -Rd options.