# Perforce revision graph - what does 'ignore' mean?

Tags: integration, perforce, p4v

What does 'ignore' mean in the perforce revision graph for a file?

I can see a lightly dotted line, the legend says 'ignore' and the action on the file is 'integrate', but what does this mean?

Comment: From the documentation: [`ignored` : file was integrated from partner-file, accepting yours.](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_integrated.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It records the fact that, when that revision was submitted, you instructed Perforce to "accept yours".

This is very useful because it tells Perforce that the reason that a certain change is in one branch, but not another, is because you explicitly specified that.

In future integrations, Perforce knows not to present that change again, so subsequent merges are cleaner and simpler.

For an example of where this is useful, see: [Proper way to ignore source files during Perforce integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870354/proper-way-to-ignore-source-files-during-perforce-integration)